# Is there a simple way to attach a skin texture to a humanod mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

I thought this would be a relatively simple thing but it turns out
nothing in Blender is simple and it appears to be a maze of information
where I cant even find the trail let alone follow it.

Comment: What is the texture made up of, is it already setup for a pelted mapping or is it a tiled/seamless texture that you could apply as a simple material texture to all faces of your object? UV Mapping is the main thing you want to look at. If you can, include screen shots of the texture and material settings as well as the model and how the UV are arranged.

Answer (score 0):

Make a texture on the side bar >>> go into edit mode on the mesh >>> select it all >>> click on "mesh" on the toolbar near the bottom >>> click on UV UNWRAP it would automatically unwrap the mesh for you.

Smart UV project works, but just unwrapping it is the better option.